# Changing result doing the same thing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I go about making it so that if I pressed S it would set a boolean to true and then if I pressed it again it would set that boolean to false in a relatively short few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `!` symbol to flip the boolean variable when the `S` key is pressed.

```
bool someBool = false;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        someBool = !someBool;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted

Comment: @MountainSideStudios You can't upvote. You don't have enough reputation to do so. You can only accept answers at this time. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) is how to accept anser. You have to wait for 8 minutes to be able to accept the answer. Also do the-same for your other questions with good answers.

Comment: @MountainSideStudios upvoting answers that already exist on SO in multiple copies is generally not recommended. So don't worry too much abount not being able to upvote this one. For future questions so consider searching for existing questions so people who answer don't have to spend they time writing personalized post for you (also some don't mind... making it harder for future visitors to find complete answers).